# usb-cam using deprecated pixel format

Tags: ros, rviz, camera, usb-cam, usb-cam-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu mate 20.04 focal and i have installed ros noetic,
I am trying to use a logitech c920 webcam, however when i run
rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node
i get the following error
[swscaler @ 0x229f390] no accelerated colorspace conversion from yuv422p to rgb24,
[swscaler@ 0x229f390] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you set the range correctly

i read that these are just warnings however, when i run
rosrun rviz rviz
it doesn't display the image from the webcam

the webcam does work though if i open it through Cheese or vlc it displays just fine

i have tried using the fixes found here

https://answers.ros.org/question/173501/problem-displaying-webcam-on-beaglebone-black-ros-hydro/

and here

https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam/issues/91

and here

https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam/issues/67

however, no of these solutions have seemed to work i've also tried changing the ffmpeg code in the usb_cam.cpp code but i haven't been able to get that to work either....
when i run
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext -d /dev/video0
i get the following
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Type: Video Capture

```
[0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    Size: Discrete 640x480
        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

i think the problem is that it's using deprecated ffmpeg code to try and convert it from yuyv to mjpeg? but i'm not sure if i'm right about this....

how do i fix this? please help.....
is there another ros package that i could try?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376295/usb-cam-using-deprecated-pixel-format/) by [golferGuy1145](https://answers.ros.org/users/73323/golferguy1145/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding `_pixel_format:="yuyv"` to the rosrun command.
I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [SamRodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/89124/samrodriguez/) with karma: 61 on 2021-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1